# Is there any way to change v-axis format as power of 10 like 0.00 x 10^# on google chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

now i am looking for the way to change the tick value as as power of 10 like 0.00 x 10^# on google chart.

currently, i use this,

```
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Population (millions)',
      scaleType: 'log',
      format: '0.00E0#'
    }
  };
```

and the chart is
[image]

so if you have any idea to change the y-axis indicator from "1.00E4" to "1.00 x 10^4", please tell me.

Comment: if you are able to calculate what the y-axis ticks should be, and hard-code them in an array, we can format appropriately...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
So.. I think i can calculate the ticks, but.. how can i format them like "1.00 x 10^4" ?

Answer (score 1):

when providing the ticks,
we can provide both the value (`v:`) and formatted value (`f:`) using object notation...

```
var options = {
  vAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: 5000, f: '5.00 x 10^3'}, {v: 10000, f: '1.00 x 10^4'}]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it by your workaround method!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized the chart by using this ticks option.

```
    ticks: [
      { v: 0.1, f: '1.00x10\u207B\u00B9' },
      { v: 0.01, f: '1.00x10\u207B\u00B2' },
      { v: 0.02, f: '' },
      { v: 0.03, f: '' },
      { v: 0.04, f: '' },
      { v: 0.05, f: '' },
      { v: 0.06, f: '' },
      { v: 0.07, f: '' },
      { v: 0.08, f: '' },
      { v: 0.09, f: '' },
      { v: 0.001, f: '1.00x10\u207B\u00B3' },
      { v: 0.002, f: '' },
      { v: 0.003, f: '' },
      { v: 0.004, f: '' },
      { v: 0.005, f: '' },
      { v: 0.006, f: '' },
      { v: 0.007, f: '' },
      { v: 0.008, f: '' },
      { v: 0.009, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0001, f: '1.00x10\u207B\u2074' },
      { v: 0.0002, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0003, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0004, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0005, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0006, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0007, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0008, f: '' },
      { v: 0.0009, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00001, f: '1.00x10\u207B\u2075' },
      { v: 0.00002, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00003, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00004, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00005, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00006, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00007, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00008, f: '' },
      { v: 0.00009, f: '' },
            ],
```